# How do i disable ssl validation/verification in java using only java code?

Tags: java

I wanted to disable or set ssl validation to false when sending to https server of mine. Can any one tell me how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'disable ssl validation'? Du you mean skip the handshale, because that won't be possible. But maybe you're thinking more like ```curl --insecure```?

Answer (score 0):

Since https protocol is designed for security purposes you are not able to disable the validation(ssl handshake). So you can simply switch your web application to http protocol.